# check doubled symbols with spirit::qi

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I need to check text for doubled symbols. For example "1+1*2" should be ok, but "1**2+3" or "--1+4*3" should not. Consider part of spirit calc example.

```
     expression =
            term[_val=_1]
            >> *(   ('+' >> term[_val+=_1])
                    |   ('-' >> term[_val-=_1])
                );

      term =
            factor[_val=_1]
            >> *(   ('*' >> factor[_val*=_1])
                |   ('/' >> factor[_val/=_1])
                );

      factor =
            double_[_val=_1]
            |   '(' >> expression[_val=_1] >> ')'
            |   ('-' >> factor[_val=_1])
            |   ('+' >> factor[_val=_1]);
```

phrase_parse returns true with the expressions like "1+++1" or "1**-1". I tried to use repeat like this:

```
      term =
            factor[_val=_1]
            >> *(   (repeat(0)[char_('*')] >> factor[_val*=_1])
                |   ('/' >> factor[_val/=_1])
                );
```

But it doesnt help. What do i miss? 
Thanks.

EDIT: Found an answer. One should compare string itrators after phrase_parse, but not phrase_parse output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. One should compare string itrators after phrase_parse, but not phrase_parse output.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, '1+++++1' is parsing correctly since factor is recursively accepting +'s (probably intended to be a unary +/-).

Split that up

```
  factor = ('-' >>  value[_val=-_1])
         | ('+' >> value[_val= _1])
         | value [_val = _1];
  value = double_ | '(' >> expression >> ')'
```